# Windows Updates caused Internet Explorer to shrink an iframe to quarter of its size

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, windows-update

Our users found an issue in which (when discovered by our IT department) Windows updates KB4012204 and KB4012216 caused an IFrame that had a list of radio buttons to shrink to a quarter of the size and add the scrollbar as seen below (I had to obfuscate some things, so excuse the ugly pic):

[image: New behavior since Windows Update]

Answer (score 0):

We weren't very successful in finding a solid solution to the issue.  The one suggestion we found from https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/win10-march-cumulative-update-kb-4013429-breaks-display-of-forms-in-ms-dynamics-crm-2011/#post-101672 did not work for us since it didn't pertain to our situation.

What I found worked for us was setting the height of the IFrame to something very high like 750px instead of just using 100%.  It works for our case, but I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered the issue and if they have a better solution to this.  If not, feel free to use this solution as a starting point if you are encountering what we found.